# R: Using colnames in data$ operation

Tags: r

I have a problem with using output of names() in data$ operation. 
The set-up of the code is:

```
list <- names(train1aM1)
list
#[1] "MOSTYPE"  "MAANTHUI" "MGEMOMV"  "MGEMLEEF" "MOSHOOFD" "MGODRK"   "MGODPR"   "MGODOV"  
#[9] "MGODGE"   "MRELGE" ......

list[1]
#[1] "MOSTYPE"

as.name(list[1])
#[1] MOSTYPE

This returns value:

train1aM1$MOSTYPE
#[1] 33 23 33 11 33 23 38 13 33 13 34 13 37 40 31 24  8  7 41 39 33 24  8 33  3 38 39 33 33 ....
```

But the following code returns NULL.

```
test <- as.name(list[1])
train1aM1$test
#NULL
```

What is wrong?

Comment: This is a manytimes duplicate but I'm too lazy to search. Reading `help("[")` will be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you!! Problem solved.